# From track+waypoints to elevation profile with waypoints

Tags: qgis, r, elevation, profile

I have a track and waypoints (1) imported in QGIS. I want to calculate the closest point from every waypoint to the track (2). Then, I want a table with data that allows me to draw an elevation profile overplotting the waypoints in R. I should generate the following data:

1. Elevation profile from the track (already achieved using the complement "Profile Tool").
2. Data for waypoints which should include three columns from data calculated from the intersection at the closest point with the track: waypoint name, distance to the beginning of the the track, elevation.

[image]